# How to install apache Jmeter on PKS (pivotal-container-service)

Tags: jmeter, pcf

I want to install Apache Jmeter on PKS (pivotal-container-service) for testing micro service on PCF.

I am not able to find any good resources ,did anyone tried and got success?

- https://hub.docker.com/r/justb4/jmeter/
- https://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2018/03/getting-started-with-vmware-pivotal-container-service-pks-part-1-overview.html
- https://network.pivotal.io/products/pcfdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into [Pivotal Container Service](https://pivotal.io/platform/pivotal-container-service) main page

> Production-ready **Kubernetes** for the enterprise

So Pivotal Container Service seems to be using [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) under the hood.

The process of installation of JMeter into Kubernetes and/or Pivotal Container Service would be as easy as creating an [Image](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/) with your own [Docker JMeter installation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/make-use-of-docker-with-jmeter-learn-how/) (or use [any existing one](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=jmeter&type=image)) and using this image in the PCS.